# Error on running automated Tableau backup using TSM in Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation, tableau-api

I am trying to automate Tableau backup in Windows.  I am using Tableau 2019.1. As the new TSM command requires a password every time we do backup, what I did was I stored the password on another file and encrypt it, and call this file when I want to execute the command. Instead of using .bat file, I use PowerShell because I am calling the credentials '.sec' file via PowerShell (I am not sure on how to do it on .bat).

Below are the sample code that I did ("MyP@ssword1" is not my real password, and the tableau backup script is what I found somewhere from Tableau community):

To encrypt password (I put it on C:\Users\Administrator.tableau\cred.sec):

```
"MyP@ssword1" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom- 
 SecureString | Out-File "c:\Users\BackupAdmin\.tableau\cred.sec"
```

My ps1 file:

```
$FilePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\.tableau\cred.sec"

$Username = "my username"

$encryptedCred = Get-Content $FilePath | ConvertTo-SecureString

$cred = New-Object System.management.Automation.PsCredential($Username,             

$encryptedCred)

$Pass = $cred.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$a=Get-Date -UFormat "%y/%m/%d"

tsm maintenance backup -f ts_backup -d -u "$Username" -p "$Pass"

$Pass = ""

tsm maintenance ziplogs -l -t -o -f "logs-$a .zip" -u "$Username" -p "$Pass"

$Pass = ""
```

On windows task scheduler,

On Actions: start a program

program/script: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

arguments: ".\tableau_backup.ps1"

start in: ""D:\Tableau Server\data\""

The error message is: "the operator or administrator has refused the request (0x800710e0)" from windows task scheduler, but if I 'run with PowerShell', this script is working as normal.

I am not sure which part that I did wrong, would someone can advise me on this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same account to encrypt password and to run scheduled task? If you use different account, it won't be able to decrypt the password.

Comment: To expand on this: SecureStrings are encrypted and decrypted int he context of a specific user. So if you encrypt it as user1 you won't be able to decrypt it as user2. Only user1 will be able to do that.

Comment: hi robdy and seth, thank you for your comment. I am using AWS for this, and using the exact snapshot of the server, with the same machine name and username (this is a new machine, there are no other user created yet and there are only system user). My issue have been solved now, the problem lies in the conditions on start in (optional), and arguments. I am suppose to use - FILE "path to .ps1" and leave the start in (optional) empty, also on settings, I was suppose to use "stop existing instance". Thanks for your help!